# How to escape '_' and '%' wildcards in Spring Data JPQL LIKE query?

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have the following method in Spring data repositiry:

```
@Query("""
    select t from ToneEntity t
    where (:title is null or (t.title like %:title%))
    and (:albumId is null or (t.album.id = :albumId))
    and (:artistId is null or (t.artist.id = :artistId))
    and (:creatorId is null or (t.creator.id = :creatorId))
""")
fun findFilteredTones(
    @Param("title") title: String?,
    @Param("albumId") albumId: Long?,
    @Param("artistId") artistId: Long?,
    @Param("creatorId") creatorId: Long?,
    pageable: Pageable
): List<ToneEntity>
```

When a title contains _ or % chars, Spring data passes them as wildcards but not as literals.
Example: I have a tone with the title 'bug_with_underscore' in the database. User on the web UI passes '*' to find tones with '*' literal in the title, but the actual result includes all tones.

How to set up automatic character escaping in LIKE queries?

Version of Spring Data JPA: 2.3.5

I found several possible solutions:

1. Use concat and replace SQL functions: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740432/escaping-values-in-spring-data-repository](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
2. Shield wildcard characters before passing them to the query: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558667/java-jpa-sql-accept-wrong-with-like](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Is there any better solution in 2022? So far, I haven't found anything better than using aspects to escape wildcard characters manually. Because this problem occurs very often in our project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing escape character constant

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.EscapeCharacter

val ESCAPE_CHARACTER: EscapeCharacter = EscapeCharacter.of('#')
```

I also manually added escape '#' to each JPQL LIKE query

```
@Query("""
    select t from ToneEntity t
    where (:title is null or (t.title like %:title%  escape '#'))
    and (:albumId is null or (t.album.id = :albumId))
    and (:artistId is null or (t.artist.id = :artistId))
    and (:creatorId is null or (t.creator.id = :creatorId))
""")
fun findFilteredTones(
    @Param("title") title: String?,
    @Param("albumId") albumId: Long?,
    @Param("artistId") artistId: Long?,
    @Param("creatorId") creatorId: Long?,
    pageable: Pageable
): List<ToneEntity>
```

This is not the best solution, but the release deadline forced me to use this approach

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, although unfortunately it didn't help me yet as this syntax is no longer valid in Spring Boot 3. I did try it in Spring Boot 2 and it worked. It's in Java but the query part shouldn't be any different.

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Movie m WHERE m.director LIKE %?#{escape([0])} escape ?#{escapeCharacter()}")
List<Movie> searchByDirectorEndsWith(String director);
```

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-like-queries#2-ordered-parameters

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I resolved it using [EscapeCharacter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/EscapeCharacter.html) by wrapping the value like

```
searchKey = EscapeCharacter.DEFAULT.escape(searchKey)
```